# bulk.find.update() vs update.collection(multi=true) in mongo

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

I am newbie to mongodb and would like to implement mongodb in my project having millions of record.Would like to know what should i prefer for update -bulk.find.update() vs update.collection with multi =true for performance.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the biggest gains `Bulk` provides are these:

1. Bulk operations send only one request to the MongoDB for the all requests in the bulk. Others send a request per document or send only for one operation type from one of `insert`, `update`, `updateOne`, `upsert` with `update` operations and `remove` .
2. Bulk can handle a lot of different cases at different lines on a code page.
3. Bulk operations can work as asynchronously. Others cannot.

But today some operations work `bulk` based. For instance `insertMany`.

If the gains above have taken into account, `update()` must show the same performance results with an `bulk.find.update()` operation.

Because `update()` can take only one query object sending to MongoDB. And `multi: true` is only an argument which specifies that the all matched documents have to be updated. This means it makes only one request on the network. Just like `Bulk` operations.

So, both of sends only one request to MongoDB and MongoDB evaluates the query clause to find the documents that'd be updated then updates them!

I had tried to find out an answer for this question on MongoDB official site but I could not.

So, an explanation from @AsyaKamsky would be great!